# how to prevent Field from auto paint it's background?

Tags: blackberry, background, paint

There is a customized CField (extends from Field) I am working on it, the platform is BlackBerry OS7.1, use java environment.

Now I want to handle the drawing things of CField all by myself, and not allow the field paint it's background automatically, so I can reuse the previous drawed elements, that will make animation effects more efficient.

I override the function:

`protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
// do nothing here
}`

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, the field still erases all previous drawed elements.

Need your kindly help, thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to override `paint` as well. [This](http://docs.blackberry.com/es-es/developers/deliverables/29251/Creating_a_custom_button_1676236_11.jsp) is a good tutorial on creating custom fields.

Comment: thank you, I just solve this matter by using Memory Bitmap. the steps are: 1)create an Bitmap object, which size equas to the CField; 2)draw on the bitmap, you see, it will never auto paint it's background; 3)rop the bitmap when CFeild.paint();